# Usar Promesa en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, socket.io

Resulta que tengo un error y no sé realmente que pueda estar pasando, pues tengo un código en Javascript que se corre en NodeJS(Express) y es básicamente una consulta que se realiza a una DB (Mysql) cada cierto tiempo, esos datos son coordenadas que envío de una APP a el servidor y la idea es que en cada nueva consulta que se realiza cada 10 segundos, me muestre por consola los nuevos datos que han llegado a la DB, el problema es que me muestra la primer consulta y cuando ingreso nuevos datos no los muestra a menos que reinicie el servidor.

Esta es la parte de la DB

```
var Getnewpoint = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    let query = `SELECT ve.idVehiculo , ST_X(gp.point) AS LATITUD, ST_Y(gp.point) AS LONGITUDE, ve.nombre, gp.id FROM vehiculos as ve , gps as gp WHERE gp.vehiculos_idvehiculo= ve.idvehiculo AND gp.id = (SELECT MAX(gpso.id) FROM gps as gpso where gpso.vehiculos_idvehiculo = ve.idvehiculo);`;

    connection.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (!err) {
                result.forEach(element => {
                // console.log(element);
                    //console.log("estos son los datos?" + JSON.stringify(element));
                });

                resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
                console.log("estos son los datos?" + JSON.stringify(result) + "\n");
            } else if (err) {
                console.log(`error: ${err}`);
                resolve(`${err}`);
            }
    });
});
```

Este fichero es un .js

```
socket.on("posicionVehiculos", function() {
    database.Getnewpoint.then(function(env) {
        env.forEach(element => {
            database.Getnewpoint
            console.log("estoy en la promesa", element.idVehiculo,element.LONGITUDE,element.LATITUD,element.id); 
            var obj={};
            obj.id = element.nombre;
            obj.lon= element.LONGITUDE;
            obj.lat= element.LATITUD;
            if(SOCKET_MONITOR_ID!=null)
            io.sockets.connected[SOCKET_MONITOR_ID].emit('monitorPrincipal',obj);
            });
    }, function(reason) {
        console.log(reason); // Error!
    });
});
```

Y este un HTML

```
function getVehiculos()
{
    SOCKET.emit("posicionVehiculos");
    console.log("estoy en getVehiculos");
    setTimeout("getVehiculos()", 10000); 
}
```

Estoy trabajando con Socket IO

Comment: Saludos, 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido, 2. Visita el recorrido para que entiendas cómo funciona el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, 3. Revisa cómo hacer preguntas aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 4. Colocar código en lugar de imágenes, le da buena calidad :D

Comment: y otra cosa, donde estaria la parte que haga que esto se ejecute cada 10 segundos?

Comment: Ya realicé la modificación a la pregunta, muchas gracias.

Comment: No se que tan equivocado esté pero los problemas del callback y de las funciones que esperan me los solucionó el async await, deberias usarlo

Comment: Ojo, creo que tu pregunta es como hacer para que algo se ejecute cada 10 segundos.. no veo ningun timer por ningun lado..

Comment: si quieres algo que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo es setInterval, el setTimeout se ejecuta luego de un tiempo determinado

Comment: De por si ya se está ejecutando cada cierto tiempo, pero ese no es este tema, la cuestión es la duda que tengo sobre si el problema es la promesa o algo con mysql.